# How to create a Datadog monitor to trigger when there is a missing metric (or a metric is zero) at the start of the month, or at a specific time

Tags: events, metrics, rules, datadog

We are trying to leverage Datadog to create a metric monitor that will trigger when something hasn't happened (an AWS event rule has not been invocated) at say, 08:00 UTC on the first of the month.

Is there a way to do this?

I've looked at metric and time shifts and count monitors but nothing obvious has jumped at me